# Angular2 with SystemJs and typescript transpiler not working

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

my configuration with typescript transpiler not working. My @angular component is not loaded. I am getting this error:
ZoneAwareError:

```
"Error: core_1.Component is not a function
  Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:64223/app/app.component.ts
  Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:64223/app/app.module.ts
  Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:64223/app/main.ts
  Loading app
    at LoaderError__Check_error_message_for_loader_stack (http://127.0.0.1:64223/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:78:11) [<root>]
    at http://127.0.0.1:64223/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:281:11 [<root>]
    at Zone.run (http://127.0.0.1:64223/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:43) [<root> => <root>]
    at http://127.0.0.1:64223/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:535:57 [<root>]
    at Zone.runTask (http://127.0.0.1:64223/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://127.0.0.1:64223/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:433:35) [<root>]"
```

I know that transpiler is't good at production, but i am using it on dev env.
So my configuration is next:

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "disableCompileOnSave": true,
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "target" : "ES5",
    "module" : "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators" : true,
    "noImplicitAny" : true
  }
}
```

**systemjs**

```
System.config({
  transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
        module: "system",
        target: "es2015",
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
        experimentalDecorators: true
    },

  map: {
      "ts": "/node_modules/plugin-typescript/lib",
      "typescript": "/node_modules/typescript",

      'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
      '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
      '@angular/common': 'node_modules/@angular/common/bundles',
      '@angular/core': 'node_modules/@angular/core/bundles',
      '@angular/compiler': 'node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles'
  },

  packages: {
    "ts": {
      "main": "plugin.js"
    },
    "typescript": {
      "main": "/lib/typescript.js",
      "meta": {
        "/lib/typescript.js": {
          "exports": "ts"
        }
      }
    },
    'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
    'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},
      '@angular/common': { main: 'common.umd.js'},
      '@angular/core': { main: 'core.umd.js'},
      '@angular/compiler': { main: 'compiler.umd.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser': { main: 'platform-browser.umd.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': { main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js'},
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular seed project</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="system.config.js"></script>
    <script>

        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "live-server"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "plugin-typescript": "^6.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

and my components and modules:

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
console.log('@angular/core');
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    myHero = 'Windstorm';
}
```

**app/app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

and **app/main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Probably something wrong with system.js config. I am having hard times last night with this, looking for help.

Comment: I recommend using the angular-cli, it takes care of all configuration settings and it's an amazing tool.

Comment: @shammelburg any examples?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error today and have found something that works.
**I had a tsconfig like this**

```
"compilerOptions": {
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"noEmitOnError": false,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5"
```

},
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}

I compared with the sample from the Angular Quickstart and noticed that they were using **commonjs**

```
"compilerOptions": {
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"noEmitOnError": false,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5"
```

},
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}

Recompiled the ts files and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the official angular 2 project generator? The angular-cli uses the Webpack now (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

Outside the Webpack facilities the angular-cli pussui component generators, services etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same problem. Try downgrading your systemjs version. I changed mine from 0.20.12 to 0.19.40 and the app suddenly started working. The suggestion came from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjF8rnK6LHTAhUH6IMKHakzA-MQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoft%2FTypeScript%2Fissues%2F14153&usg=AFQjCNGLatD6ia02CiypQiUvZPXg1LiwOw). Note that I have `"module": "system"` in tsconfig. Of course you'll need to remove the caret from the systemjs version string.